# Java HTTP webbit how to send/receive message

Tags: java, http, client-server

I have a server and a client,
on the server side i have this handler

```
 @Override
 public void handleHttpRequest(HttpRequest httpRequest,
 HttpResponse httpResponse,
 HttpControl httpControl) throws Exception {
 // ..
 }
```

The question is how to send data from the client side and what method in the server side will contain the data sent?

If there is a better way to perform the communication using webbit, it will be welcomed too.

Answer (score 1):

In a POST request, the parameters are sent as a body of the request, after the headers.

To do a POST with HttpURLConnection, you need to write the parameters to the connection after you have opened the connection.

This code should get you started:

```
String urlParameters = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
String request = "http://example.com/index.php";
URL url = new URL(request); 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
connection.setUseCaches (false);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

Alternatively you could use this helper to send POST the request and get the request

```
    public static String getStringContent(String uri, String postData, 
    HashMap<String, String> headers) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
    request.setURI(new URI(uri));
    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(postData));
    for(Entry<String, String> s : headers.entrySet())
    {
        request.setHeader(s.getKey(), s.getValue());
    }
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    {
        throw new Exception(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String s;
    while(true )
    {
        s = buf.readLine();
        if(s==null || s.length()==0)
            break;
        sb.append(s);

    }
    buf.close();
    ips.close();
    return sb.toString();
   }
```

Comment: so the question is .. in the handler function i written in my question, where exactly is the data i sent using the POST request?

Comment: For the first example, its urlParameters, for the latter, its passed through the parameters. Is that alright?

Comment: No, I mean in this function 
public void handleHttpRequest(HttpRequest httpRequest,
 HttpResponse httpResponse,
 HttpControl httpControl) 
where can i find the data?
for example shouldn't it be httpRequest.body() ? because i tried it and it didn't work

Comment: The code I've given you gives you the response so you won't need that :)

Comment: But i'm responsible for the server side also :D , this is the main problem actually , because i'm able to send some data to the server but i've no idea how to handle these data and respond correctly.

Comment: On your server side, create a PHP script that when the request is sent to it, it gives back a response based on the parameters passed to it. Do you want some sample code?

Comment: the problem is i can only use webbit server with java, if you can help that would be great!

Comment: Sorry, I'm only 14 and just started out on server-client stuff, hope I helped tho :D

Answer (score 0):

Usually one will extend HttpServlet and override doGet.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

I am not familiar with webbit but I do not think it is a Servlet webserver.  It mentions that it serves static pages.